# 2 4 port routers with 8 port switch

Tags: router

How should I hook this up so all computers (8 - 10) be able to talk to one another.  Have 1 ISP with 1 voice modem and standard modem from ISP.  I have tried different hookups but can't get them all to talk.  Please help!!

Thanks for your help,
Tom

Comment: Can you provide some more info.  You say you are using an 8 port switch with "routers" but do not specify how many routers you are using.  What type of routers are you using (do they have DD-WRT)?  Are all of your computers right next to each other?  Are you wanting all wired, all wireless, or a combination of connections?  With out this info I would just tell you to make sure you only have one DHCP server on your system and to also make sure your all of your computers are using the same subnet mask.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the routers and/or switch have a MDI/MDIX (uplink) port, you'll need crossover cables to connect the routers to the switch.

Comment: If they're relatively new, the switches and/or routers should support Auto MDI/MDIX negotiation.

Answer (score -1):

If you daisy chain 2 routers together the wrong way you will be on 2 different subnets i.e.(192.168.1.xxx for some computers and others could be on 192.168.2.xxx) Make sure that one router the one coming from the modem is the only router that is connected via the wan port. Once all of the router and switches are connected and on the same subnet turn off DHCP on the ones that are not connected to the router,